# Error return object Rest API JSON Springboot with a database Oracle : Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, web-services, datetime-format

I use springboot to return a json object from a database oracle , whene I call the API **http://localhost:8074/signal/all**  I have the error below

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be
> yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]   at java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(Unknown
> Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]

Type Date in my database oracle is **Date**  (example : **15/10/2020**)

**- Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SIGNAL")
public class Signal implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "SIG_MATR")
    private String sigMatr;
    private String sigSitu;
    private String sigSexe;
    @JsonIgnore
    @DateTimeFormat(style = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS")
    private Date sigDate;
```

I tested to use annotation **@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)** , and I have use **@JsonIgnore** ti ignore the return of this column , but is not resolve the problem

**- Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/signal")
public class SignalController {
    
    @Autowired
    private SignalRepository dao;


    @GetMapping("/all")
    public Iterable<Signal> allCollab() {
        return dao.findAll();
    }
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date` and `Timestamp`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. For a date without time of day use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @OleV.V. it's worked with LocalDate , Thank you

Comment: You may want to post that as an answer to your own question? Please give details enough that others can do like you did, and I shall be happy to upvote.